# How to turn on/off in run-time JAX-RS filter/interceptor

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, interceptor

I have a logging filter (or interceptor) which logs the HTTP request and response details to database. Because of performance reason sometime I would like to turn the filter on and off in run-time based on a value from example a *.properties file.

This is my JAX-RS filter:

```
@Provider
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // logging request details to database
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        // logging response details to database
    }
}
```

I can add a `if` condition at the beginning of the filter but that is not what I would like to do. I would like to attach/detach the filter somehow if it is possible.

Comment: You cant........

Comment: What is wrong with an if?

Comment: That would be so elegant without 'if'.

Comment: just change the logging levels that you output to console/file

Comment: I am "logging" to database... Anyway, I understood that there is no way to attach/detach filter or interceptor.